# Are database configuration questions appropriate for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, scope

Questions about how to solve problems using complicated queries are certainly on-topic for Stack Overflow. Many hard query problems also require specific fine tuning of the database server. Are questions related to that type of configuration appropriate for Stack Overflow?

The "unique to software development" requirement in [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) is the one I'm not sure about. It seems like database configuration might also fall under the scope of [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/).

Where is the appropriate line for these types of questions? Should anything configuration related be asked on a different Stack Exchange site? Or is it appropriate to ask configuration related questions when specifically related to a programming problem?

I was asking preemptively before posting instead of asking my question in the wrong place. I went ahead and posted it on the DBA site - [Is there a configuration setting for how many pages ANALYZE will scan?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/66256/39273)

The Stack Overflow version would have included more details about table structure and query. Then it would have asked, "Can `ANALYZE` be configured to scan more pages so that the Query Planner can do a better job on this query?"

Comment: "Many hard query problems also require specific fine tuning of the database server." If it was ***strictly*** a configuration question, I would say that it belongs on [dba.se], but you're saying it's also related to a query. Do you have a specific example? If the problem is so complicated that it involves special configurations for the database, I might be inclined to say that it belongs on DBA.SE then...but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Cupcake I added an example of the questions I was formulating.