# Do [asterisk] server configuration questions belong on Stack Overflow or Server Fault?

Tags: discussion, tags, scope

Questions regularly appear on Stack Overflow about [asterisk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asterisk), the telephony server. Unless there's a clear development issue (using the API for example) I routinely vote to migrate them to Server Fault.

Today [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944943/custom-cdr-fields-for-outgoing-calls-using-asterisk?noredirect=1#comment36884366_23944943) was asked. The content appears to relate purely to configuration, but the OP suggests that he's 'programming the dialplan'.

The code that's been posted looks like a series of configuration directives rather than code, although there may be some macro expansion going on here.

Is this on-topic for Stack Overflow, or is it really a configuration issue for Server Fault?

Comment: I would say that since configuring the proper environment for your program to run in is part of many programming projects, many questions about server configuration are helpful to programmers in particular.

Answer (score 35):

I disagree, at least with this specific question.

The Asterisk dialplan language - be it the traditional language or AEL (Asterisk Extension Language) - is a domain specific scripting language. If questions regarding it aren't appropriate, then questions involving bash should not be appropriate either.

[Edit]: Using the test of Turing Complete is somewhat arbitrary, as there are non-Turing Complete languages that have questions on Stack Overflow, but I'll bite.

Asterisk's dialplan language contains sufficient control and variable expression capabilities that you can easily write a program that simulates a Turing machine. You can:

1. Store/retrieve values
2. Perform conditional logic and branching
3. Write functions
4. String manipulation

[Edit 2]: For what it's worth, there are plenty of off topic Asterisk questions. A prime example is this one:

[Attended Transfer to gxw410x sip trunk Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23942441/attended-transfer-to-gxw410x-sip-trunk-failed)

However, just because there are a plethora of configuration questions does not mean that all questions should be down voted and removed. To be frank, if you're going to down vote and flag a question, you should probably understand the domain of the question before doing so.

Comment: I'm trying to clarify my understanding so that I can flag or downvote some of these appropriately. You suggest we move on if we can't distinguish between on-topic and off-topic questions. The problem then is that subsequent visitors see them and assume they can post similar questions. The Turing Complete test may be inappropriate here, but it remains the case that the only thing one can do with the Asterisk language is 'program' or 'configure' Asterisk switches. I leave the words in quotes because the distinction is the essence of my question.

Comment: I voted to reopen. I'd say this question is acceptable both on SO and SF. In border-cases like this I think we should let the question live, taking into account that it seems to be a good question.

Comment: Can you loop or recurse or evaluate a string in the language?  Even a regular expression can do if.

Comment: Matt, can you weigh in here? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256701/are-database-configuration-questions-appropriate-for-so

Comment: @Yakk Yes, you can loop and evaluate strings in the language.

Comment: @MikeW: As far as I know, there are no StackOverflow rules regarding domain specific languages. While I may prefer to see more Asterisk related questions on ServerFault, closing questions which do not violate the rules of StackOverflow is a poor way to achieve that goal. Effective moderation requires restraint and knowledge of what you are moderating; closing this particular issue failed both tests.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I can try. My opinions on the appropriateness of database configuration is bound to be limited (not my area of expertise).

Comment: @mattjordan You have admitted that many Asterisk questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow. I took a view. My view was disputed so I raised the question here. Subsequent events were outside my control. I've learned something and hopefully the community as a whole has benefitted from the debate. Using the word 'programming' in a question doesn't automatically make it valid. People talk of 'programming' their video recorders such a question would not be accepted here. If those with real expertise in this area were more active in moderating it then perhaps none of this would have been an issue.

Comment: I've worked in environments where, as an example, things like Tomcat configuration was considered a system admin duty. This is certainly a grey area, and I lean towards keeping such content on Stack Overflow since we should [Respect the community -- your own, and others'](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/).

Answer (score 8):

I think that Asterisk dial plan has more to do with programming than CSS styling of web pages. Nobody considers CSS related questions as off-topic here. In this case you define some workflow with conditional branches and even without Turing completeness it's enough to classify this question as related to programming.

Generally questions about server software can be off-topic or not depending on the nature of the question.

Comment: CSS is squarely in the domain of programming.  Nobody argues that CSS isn't programming-related.

Comment: @RobertHarvey that's exactly what I said. Even if it's not a programming language, everybody knows it's related to programming. It doesn't look like a programming language and lacks most of PL features. So when I compare it to Asterisk dial plan...the answer seems to be obvious.

Comment: Asterisk Dial Plan is a domain-specific scripting language, in an arguably small domain.  While it may be programming-related, it's not even in the same ballpark as CSS.

Comment: @RobertHarvey CSS is a domain-specific styling configuration ("language" is a bit much, it's really a glorified .ini file), in an inarguably LARGE domain. Do we embrace it because its domain is large, or because it's inextricably tied to JS/jQuery/web dev questions? If the former, we should drop Asterisk. If the latter, we should accept both.

Comment: @AdamSmith: I'm just not sure, that's all.  It seemed self-evident to me when I saw the original Asterisk question that it was off-topic, but I'm not an Asterisk expert, and apparently, if it walks like a duck, etc.  How do you separate configuration from programming? Are questions about programming Cisco routers fair game?  Compare this question with http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256701/are-database-configuration-questions-appropriate-for-so

Comment: Except that programming a Cisco router does not involve a language. Like I said, both "traditional" Asterisk dialplan language and Asterisk Extension Language (AEL) happen to only be interpreted by Asterisk. You could have other interpreters. Would they ever exist? Probably not: but that doesn't change the ability or power of the languages themselves.

Asterisk dialplan can also be programmed in Lua: are those questions not allowed? If I used AGI to push my dialplan execution to Python, would that be rejected?

Comment: And, despite me pushing for dialplan programming questions to not be closed, I will admit that the vast majority of Asterisk related questions should be asked on ServerFault. It's not hard for an Asterisk developer to determine which is which; admittedly, I would expect a non-Asterisk developer to have a hard time telling the difference between scripting in the dialplan and an excerpt from some .conf file. My primary concern here is that someone who clearly did not know the difference decided to moderate these questions: that is, quite frankly, scary.

Comment: @MattJordan: Meh. The question was reopened by five community members.  The system works.  I'm still not fully convinced that every domain-specific configuration language for every possible appliance out there needs to be supported on Stack Overflow anyway, and it really should be obvious to the casual observer whether or not we're talking about programming (i.e. it should not require expert knowledge to make the determination).

Comment: @RobertHarvey, would you consider a scripting DSL in an ERP system to be appropriate fodder for SO?  Asterisk and most ERP systems have about the same mix of configurability and programmability.